# Visual Studio Code + ForceCode not working?

Tags: ide, mavensmate, git, developer-productivity

With MavensMate no longer being developed, I've shifted over to VS Code with the VisualCode plugin.  Our process is to focus around Git, so every morning we pull the newest code from the repo, merge into our branches, and compile.

Well when I hit compile, I get:
Running the contributed command:'ForceCode.compile' failed.

And I can't figure out what I can do to compile the collection of files I have, without going one at a time through the entire list, hoping there's no circular logic.

Open to ideas as to what I might be doing wrong, as I'm relatively new to both VS Code and ForceCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a know issue in the library:

[Force: Get Class, Page or Trigger stopped working after last release #101](https://github.com/celador/ForceCode/issues/101)

you can get updates through the above link.

AdamEdmonds posted a "workaround" :

> - Update VSCode to the latest version (1.13.1)
> - Remove ForceCode extension and dependencies
> - Reload VSCode
> - Install ForceCode and dependencies
> - Reload VSCode
> - Remove ForceCode only leave dependencies
> - Reload VSCode
> - Install ForceCode
> - Reload ForceCode

Comment: I'm already at VS Code 1.14.2.
I followed the other steps and now the error has changed to:
"command 'ForceCode.compile' not found"

Comment: I went through the link you provided (thank you by the way) and tried the manual deletion of the plugins, then re-installing... and now I'm back to "Running the contributed command:'ForceCode.compile' failed."...

Comment: then you should report the issue and track it on github, since this seems like a library issue as mentioned. i believe there are other libraries out there that you can try

Comment: no problem :thumbsup:

Comment: Not really a "Solution" but the answer "It's broken" is good enough for me to call it an answer :)

Comment: @ScriptMonkey did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @Dante In a way... I found that the "Save/Deploy/Compile" command didn't bulk compile, but if you have a package.xml file (if you were using ant/mavens/etc previously) then you can use the ForceCode Menu and select "Deploy Package" it seems to work fine.  Unfortunately I then had a compile error (and it didn't say more than that) so I call that progress, but unfortunately I had to go back to MM for a bit to actually get work done lol

Comment: I tried the steps but I am not able to start the forceCode or login the Org